# Android SQLlite Get List of Columns from Empty Table

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

Using Android SQL, I'm trying to get a list of the columns from an SQL table which is empty.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor ti = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info("+myTable+")", null);
        if ( ti.moveToFirst() ) {
            do {
               output.add(ti.getString(1));
            } while (ti.moveToNext());
        }
        ti.close();
        db.close();
        return output;
```

The resulting list Appears just the word INTEGER, while the database has many columns. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is i use to retrieve column name in string:

```
SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
(some code here...)
mDataBase = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor dbCursor = mDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
```

or this :

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0", null);
try {
    String[] columnNames = c.columnNames();
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name is returned in the column named `name`:

```
...
int nameColIdx = ti.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
...
output.add(ti.getString(nameColIdx));
...
```